# Why am I getting an 'undefined' error but the code is working in my Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I made this UI.registerHelper:

```
UI.registerHelper('addressCityName', function(id) {
    "use strict";
        return Cities.findOne({_id: id }).name
})
```

This allows me to access the `name` property of the linked `city` id in my Addresses collection.

It works in the browser, but in the console I get an error that says: `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

If I remove the `name` property from the UI.registerHelper return value, the error goes away but the browser no longer shows the city name.

What is up with this and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is it because the Cities collection isn't ready yet?

Comment: Probs because your subscription isn't ready when the helper runs for the first time - try wrapping the block in `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}...{{/if}}` so the helper only runs after the subscription is ready

Comment: That didn't work. The error stays the same.

Comment: yes, on reflection, not sure that would make a difference to a global helper rather than a template helper. Given that you get an error the first time the helper runs, but eventually it returns correctly, I'm almost positive that @pankaj-jatav's answer is what you need.

Comment: Also, note that `UI.registerHelper` is deprecated in favour of `Template.registerHelper` (but can't see this being your issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to get the name using `Cities.findOne({_id: id }).name`. But your subscription was not ready on client side. So the output of `Cities.findOne({_id: id })` is undefined.

So if your try to get `Cities.findOne({_id: id }).name` so if you visualize your output will be like `undefined.name`. So this is the reason you are getting the error.

To solving the issue you can add a if condition and it will solve the issue.

```
UI.registerHelper('addressCityName', function(id) {
    "use strict";
        if(Cities.findOne({_id: id })) {
            return Cities.findOne({_id: id }).name
        }
})
```

Comment: Well, I know the if statement will return because it is showing the name in the html.

Comment: @webmagnets Note that the helper will run and re-run multiple times. The issue is that the first time it runs, your subscription isn't ready so you get a TypeError. When the subscription is ready, the helper runs again and returns correctly. So all you're doing here is avoiding the initial TypeError.

Comment: Thanks. However, I added the if statement and I still get the same error.

Comment: @webmagnets are you sure it's the *same* error? If it's the same error (i.e. `can't read property "name" of undefined`) then `Cities.findOne(...)` must be `undefined` in which case the if statement wouldn't run and the helper wouldn't return anything at all. Can you check the error statement again? And maybe post your template code?

Comment: The error is gone now. I'm not sure what happened. Anyway, adding the if statement seems to have fixed it. Thanks.